# @SpringBootTest not overriding logging level

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-test

To set the log level to ERROR while testing, in a Sprig Boot application I have annotated my test classes as below.

```
@SpringBootTest({
    "logging.level.root=ERROR",
    "other.property=is-properly-overridden"
})
```

But the log level is not getting overridden. Other properties are getting properly overridden, though.

Any idea why the above won't work for logging?

Comment: have you tried with actual packages, and not `root`?

Comment: Yes, actual packages are working.